# using keras model fit multiple times for each training dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I have time series 10 datafiles. Out of which I am training a LSTM model with 5 datafiles, validation using 3 files and test using 2 files. I have used fit_generator from Keras and have written one generator function for both of the training and validation dataframes. But unfortunately during prediction it's initial predictions are very higher than original target.

On the other side if I use model.fit for each dataframe then comparatively I am getting better result. My question: "is it right approach for time series data where each of the datafiles are separate (e.g, each contains ratings from 0 hr to 24 hrs) to use fit on each iteration for each of the datafiles?"

```py
for scaled_dataset in training_list:

    reframed_new = series_to_supervised(scaled_dataset, n_in, n_out)


    values = reframed_new.values
    train = values
    # split into input and outputs
    train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
    # reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
    train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=475, validation_data=None, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

In my code training list contains all the separate 5 dataframes. So in each iteration I am fitting one model. Can anyone please tell me if it's right approach or not
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting better results", in **training accuracy**, **validation accuracy** ? Also, how are your files distributed, does each represent a different period ?

Comment: Better result means w.r.t. test RMSE and also in training accuracy. Files are distributed for example for each month one file

Comment: Ok, so you must use previous files as training and validate on future files otherwise you are leaking information in the model.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton my question is about the training code style. Is it right approach to fit a model for each datafile? or it does not work with time series data files if I fit a model in a loop for each data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I understood from your question:

- You have 10 different Time Series files, all of them contain seperate data, ranging from 0hrs to 24hrs. My first question is what is the sequence of these files, meaning does file no. 1 and file no. 2 and so on belong same sequence ?

  1. If YES, you can try to append these dataframes and train a simple forecasting model and see the results.
  2. As all your files ranges from 0hrs to 24hrs, you can set `batch_size` equal to your file 
     length. Generator function will be useful in the situation where you don't know the end of your dataset or if your time series are of different length.

If No, you have to train different models for different time series.

Comment: If I go with choice 1. then can you please elaborate the simple forecasting model? for example as you suggested I have list of 5 dataframes and for each dataframe I will fit the model . Am i right?

Comment: If all these dataframes are forming part of one continuous time series, then you can go with the approach you described above. Only change would be, instead of iterating on different data frames, you need to construct a single data frame and fit the model on top of it. Without knowing much about data, it would be naive of me to suggest anything else.

Comment: Please forget about the example with 0 hr to 24 hrs, I said it to make an example.  I Have 65 files, each starts with sequence 0, increased by time stamp 1 (e.g.,0,1,2,3), some contains 2400 rows, some 2000 rows. Now I can't concate all of these because one file is 0-2000 and the next starts with 0-2400. SO I tried two approaches,1) one is using for loop and on each iteration model.fit one each file . 2) other one is using fit_generator also in the loop for each file. Please comment which one is right? thanks in advance